# Android -replace running fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I am implementing a navigation drawer into my app, and navigation drawers recomend using fragments, and to just change the running fragment when the user selects something from the navigation drawer. When ever I try to replace the current fragment with a new fragment, my app crashes. here is the code I am using to replace the fragment.

```
Body newFragment = new Body();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this
            // fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.llhome, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
```

Edit: below is my logcat

```
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.Body.<init>(Body.java:31)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.MainActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:129)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1060)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2516)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3170)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-18 13:53:10.142: E/AndroidRuntime(17700):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please post the log of the crash you see in Logcat?

Comment: Can you post Body.java line 31 (possibly the constructor?)

Comment: @forgivegod nvm I fixed it

Comment: @user222786, How did you do to fix it? I'm curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a NPE at this line `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager .beginTransaction();`

Replace your `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();` by the following one:

`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getFragmentManager();`

Let me know about your progress ;)